# Queries in DFC and WDK in documentum

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

I have below queries in DFC and WDK:-

1) TBO is type base objects and is for specific object type in documentum. SBO is for global use. Can we make a SBO code to act like a TBO, if yes then how? How can I make my SBO specific for a particular object type.

2) How can I call a behavior class from an action.xml in WDK? If I dont want to use the component in my WDK customization. Any examples to support these queries will be appreciable.

3) Why is scope required in WDK? What is its role and can scope override over privileges in terms of hierarchy. If a user is provided a scope for a component in WDK but he/she doesnt have sufficient privileges to access it in documentum. Can the user still access the particular component?

4) Can folder security values  override basic object level permissions? Which will come first folder security or basic level permissions or privileges?

Thanks!!
Deb

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour on how to ask practical, detailed questions, and please ask one question per question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not kind of question for SO, at least in most parts. However:

1.) TBO and SBO are just architectural approaches for specific requirements. If you have specific code that you want to run for objects of specific type and not only for objects of subtypes, than you need to change object model to apply logic for all objects in type hierarchy. This isn't a problem with Documentum object/type model.

For example: You have **custom_document** as *subtype* of dm_document and **custom_child1_document** and **custom_child2_document**, both *subtypes* of custom_document. You have TBO set to custom_child2_document. 
You don't want to apply SBO to have custom logic  available everything under dm_document. 
Just add TBO to type custom_documentm and you'll have your logic for all types under dm_document.

2.) You cannot call behavior class without invoking component. If you have specific code you want run from other places, isolate it at some other place and run it at will.

3.) You don't need to specify scope for your WDK configuration. However, once you learn WDK in details you will find it useful.

4.) Folder is object. You need to know that when you access objects via folders you need access permission for both folder and document linked to that folder (*Read* level is enough). You need only permissions on object id you access that object from DQL for instance. Basic and extended permissions are meant to be used in specific cases, you don't need extended permissions to read object content if you have *Read* basic permission on your object. However you need *Relate* basic permission + *Run procedure* extended permsission on target Workflow to start workflow with that specific object as attachment/package. Different rules go when you want to add object inside specific folder. But this is long story.

Regarding folder security - check [this](http://msroth.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/what-does-folder-security-really-do/) article.